# Is there a way to use Jetty (or Tomcat)'s servlet's engine only (remove all JSP functionality)?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jetty

I have tried first Jetty, because they advertised it was designed with a modularity in mind from scratch but after commenting the line   "--module=jsp" in:

```
{jetty.home}/start.ini
{jetty.home}/demo-base/start.d/jsp.ini
```

Lots of JSP functionality is being loaded:

```
_STOP_PORT=65521
_STOP_KEY="stop_now_123"

java -jar ../start.jar STOP.PORT="${_STOP_PORT}" STOP.KEY="${_STOP_KEY}" --list-modules=jsp

 Available Modules:
 ==================
 tags: [jsp]

 Enabled Modules:
 ================
     0) ext             ${jetty.base}/start.d/ext.ini
     1) resources       ${jetty.base}/start.d/resources.ini
     2) server          ${jetty.base}/start.d/server.ini
     3) jndi            ${jetty.base}/start.d/jndi.ini
     4) security        transitive provider of security for webapp
                        transitive provider of security for plus
     5) servlet         transitive provider of servlet for webapp
                        transitive provider of servlet for servlets
                        transitive provider of servlet for jsp
     6) webapp          transitive provider of webapp for plus
                        transitive provider of webapp for deploy
                        init template available with --add-to-start=webapp
     7) plus            transitive provider of plus for annotations
     8) annotations     ${jetty.base}/start.d/annotations.ini
     9) apache-jsp      transitive provider of apache-jsp for jsp
    10) apache-jstl     transitive provider of apache-jstl for jstl
    11) client          ${jetty.base}/start.d/client.ini
    12) continuation    ${jetty.base}/start.d/continuation.ini
    13) deploy          ${jetty.base}/start.d/deploy.ini
    14) http            ${jetty.base}/start.d/http.ini
    15) ssl             transitive provider of ssl for https
                        init template available with --add-to-start=ssl
    16) https           ${jetty.base}/start.d/https.ini
    17) jaas            ${jetty.base}/start.d/demo.ini
    18) jsp             ${jetty.base}/start.d/jsp.ini
    19) jstl            ${jetty.base}/start.d/jstl.ini
    20) rewrite         ${jetty.base}/start.d/demo.ini
    21) servlets        ${jetty.base}/start.d/servlets.ini
    22) websocket       ${jetty.base}/start.d/demo.ini
```

~
 As a test I also started Jetty and logged all loaded classes while using its JSP test pages (even though JSP modules were supposedly not used by jetty's start up engine)

```
_LOG_FL="jetty_startup_loaded_classes_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log"

java  -d64 -server -verbose:class -jar ../start.jar STOP.PORT="${_STOP_PORT}" STOP.KEY="${_STOP_KEY}") > "${_LOG_FL}" 2>&1

$ cat "${_LOG_FL}" | grep jsp > "${_LOG_FL}"_jsp_classes_lines.log

$ ls -l "${_LOG_FL}"_jsp_classes_lines.log

$ wc -l "${_LOG_FL}"_jsp_classes_lines.log

$ cat "${_LOG_FL}"_jsp_classes_lines.log | grep "\[Loaded org.apache.jsp.jsp"
[Loaded org.apache.jsp.jsp.dump_jsp from file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-3200093898214200160.dir/jsp/]
[Loaded org.apache.jsp.jsp.bean1_jsp from file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-3200093898214200160.dir/jsp/]
[Loaded org.apache.jsp.jsp.bean2_jsp from file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-3200093898214200160.dir/jsp/]
[Loaded org.apache.jsp.jsp.tag_jsp from file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-3200093898214200160.dir/jsp/]
[Loaded org.apache.jsp.jsp.tagfile_jsp from file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-3200093898214200160.dir/jsp/]
[Loaded org.apache.jsp.jsp.tagfile_jsp$Helper from file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-3200093898214200160.dir/jsp/]
[Loaded org.apache.jsp.jsp.tag2_jsp from file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-3200093898214200160.dir/jsp/]
[Loaded org.apache.jsp.jsp.tag2_jsp$Helper from file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-3200093898214200160.dir/jsp/]
[Loaded org.apache.jsp.jsp.expr_jsp from file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-3200093898214200160.dir/jsp/]
[Loaded org.apache.jsp.jsp.foo.foo_jsp from file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-3200093898214200160.dir/jsp/]
```

~
 lbrtchx

Comment: Following suggestions: I did:

Answer (score 0):

You need disable `--module=jstl` also this depends of `jsp` module.

```
 Module: jstl  
       : Enables JSTL for all webapplications deployed on the server  
 Depend: jsp, apache-jstl
```

Ref: [Managing Startup Modules](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/startup-modules.html)

Comment: Note: other modules depend on `jstl` (eg: `cdi` and `jfx`)

Comment: so, what do you do in this case? Is the dependency of cdi and jfx on jstl too deep? Any hints on how to code these dependencies as plain interfaces,  property files or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

Following Sierra's and Erdfelt's suggestions, I did remove all jsp and jslt modules dependency and moved {jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp away from {jetty.home}. Everything seems to be working fine, but when I tried to stop jetty I got:

```
$ time java -jar ../start.jar STOP.PORT="${_STOP_PORT}" STOP.KEY="${_STOP_KEY}" --stop
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.stop(Main.java:576)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.stop(Main.java:519)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.doStop(Main.java:507)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:402)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)

Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
 java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information

real    2m8.334s
user    0m1.737s
sys 0m0.193s
```

~
 All I will have to do is check out those stop lines and the corresponding start ones in org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main. I still wonder about how my monkey way may have affected some internal dependencies and reimplementing cdi and jfx without JSPs

Comment: Actually, those problems seem to relate to calls home back to webtide.com. If you choose to disconnect yourself from the Internet while pre-coding, there is a very long delay of 2m8s before jetty does shut down. Running wireshark gives you more ideas. I wonder why webtide.com gets involved in your shutting down/restarting the jetty server during your coding cycles. If anyone has any kind of explanation for that I would like to hear it. Mom told me not to talk to strangers and to remain connected to the Internet the possibly least time I could ;-)